# Optimal use of type and routing of a simple blog application in elasticsearch

Tags: performance, lucene, elasticsearch, blogs

Let's assume we have a simple blog application, having **users** who write a blog **posts** and who can leave **comments** in a blog. I'm thinking about the optimal solution from a performance perspective when using elasticsearch which relies on lucene indexes. Further, the number of shards is set to 5 for this example.

If I put the users, posts and comments in *seperate* indexes elasticsearch ends up searching in **3x5=15 shards** when I want to display the blog post with the corresponding comments and the user/author information.

Another possibiltiy is to have *one* index containing the *_type* users, posts and comments. Showing the same information again, elasticsearch would have to search in **5 shards**, since a new _type does not mean a new lucene index (correct me if I'm wrong)

Let's add some complexity now. using the *_routing* parameter: I would use user_id as the routing for users, user_id of the author from the blog post for posts and the same for comments (user_id auf author of blog post instead of user_id of the comment).

Having the three indexes again, we end up looking in **3 shards**, since routing would keep all information together.

Having one index with different types, there is a search in just **1 shard** for all the information.

Are the assumptions correct and is there a more efficient way to solve this? What are the flaws by using the one-shard-solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is a general rule for designing data storage. Sharding helps you with scaling writes and replication helps you with scaling reads.

In case of Elasticsearch, you can easily limit every search request hitting all the shards by using `routing`.

Also, you are correct when you say that new `_type` does not mean new Lucene index. New shard means new Lucene index, which stores all the data that belongs to that shard.

All your assumptions are correct. You should use `routing` especially if you are looking at a larger number of shards in the future spread across more than 1 elasticsearch nodes running on different machines. `routing` is a good thing.

IMHO, your last solution of having 1 index with different types should work. I don't think there will be a lot of performance hits. For searching on users, blog posts and comments at the same time, use the [Multi Search API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html) to optimize on making multiple requests on ES and getting all the result at once.

Since `blog_posts` and `comments` are related and you may want to have related search on theme, you can consider the following design as well. Use 1 index with the following types: `users` and `blog_posts`. The `blog_posts` type will have documents for blog posts with comments inside them (as [nested types](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html)). This can help you with doing faceting on blog posts if that is something you may want in the future by firing just a single request instead of multiple requests (1 for blog posts and 1 for comments). The disadvantage would be that if you allow comments to be edited/deleted (which I think you would), every time you update the document in Elasticsearch, the document is not really updated but indexed again and the old one is just marked deleted. This may or may not become a performance issue depending upon your setup and traffic. But these documents that are marked deleted actually get deleted on segment merges. Its your call. So write your application and benchmark. That's the best way.

Basically it is possible to maintain relationships inside Elasticsearch (not exactly powerful like an RDBMS but it does the work). There is also [Parents/Childrens](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#parent-children) documents that you may want to look into. And lastly, there is a great blog post on [managing relations inside Elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/managing-relations-inside-elasticsearch/) that can be very helpful to understand how to design your data storage.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer - damn, I cannot vote you up, since I need 15 points as a new user. (I will revisit this and vote for you!). The idea with nested types is indeed good, especially if I don't expect too much comments on blog posts. I still have two open elasticsearch questions that did not got any replies so far - is there something to take care of as a new stackoverflow user?

Comment: Good to know that I was able to help. Let me check your other questions. I might be able to help. And there is nothing else you have to do as a new user. You can upvote my answer later but if it helped you, you can also go ahead and accept it as the correct answer.